# What is a MOTU?

Tags: development, motu

Also,how can I become one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the launchpad page https://launchpad.net/~motu

The MOTU Team looks after all of the packages in Universe and Multiverse in Ubuntu.

http://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU

The Masters of the Universe take care of the Ubuntu Universe packages, fix bugs, add new packages, or remove obsolete ones from the Ubuntu archive.

If you want to join, be sure to read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU/GettingStarted to understand what is required from you. We look forward to see you in the team soon!

--

Also some more info here

http://behindthecircle.org/