# How to download, modify, build and install a Debian source package?

Tags: package-management, compiling

If I want to make minor changes to the source code of a Debian package, how do I go about downloading, incrementing the package version, building the (modified) source, and installing it on my computer?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功 This question is not a duplicate of mine. It doesn't touch on modifying and rebuilding the deb package, incrementing the package version etc. It's just about downloading the source.

Comment: I think it does ask for how to build as well: "get the source code for these applications as well as update them?", "I would like to add features". This one is better phrased of course :-)

Comment: @sashoalm: Please read the top answer of that question: “To build a package from source, first […]. Then use `dpkg-buildpackage` to create a `.deb` file.” That sounds a lot like instructions to (re-)build Debian packages to me.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it. The first one is the classic form, you'll get the source with `apt-get`. The second is *the new [ubuntu] way* uses the *bzr* command.

### Classic

```
 $ apt-get source package
```

Then you'll be able to modify it:

```
 $ cd package
 $ vim some_file
```

Rebuild it:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep package
$ dch -i (which will open your editor to edit the changefile, here's where you can increment the package version)

$ debuild -us -uc -b
```

And install it:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i ../package.deb
```

---

### New Ubuntu Approach

The new way (the Ubuntu way) is by using bzr branches, you'll get the code by using:

```
$ bzr branch lp:ubuntu/package #which will download the latest ubuntu package (the precise one)

$ bzr branch lp:ubuntu/oneiric/package #to get the package in oneiric
```

You can also get the code using:

```
$ pull-lp-source package #lp-source is part of the ubuntu-dev-tools pkg
```

`pull-lp-source` used to be called just `lp-source` in older versions.

Then you'll be able to edit it:

```
$ cd package 
$ vim some_file
```

Rebuild it:

```
$ dch -i 
$ debcommit
$ bzr bd -- -b -us -uc
```

And install it:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i ../package.deb
```

I recommend that you check the [Ubuntu packaging guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/) out to know the details.

Also you might encounter problems if the package depends of others.

Comment: Using `apt-get source openjdk-7` took around 2 minutes for me, while using `bzr branch` took over an hour and I decided to kill the process. I'm wondering what would be the usefulness of this "new approach".

Comment: many thanks I did it, just need to install before: 
apt-get install dpkg-dev 
apt-get install dchroot devscripts 
apt-get install fakeroot

Comment: You need `sudo apt-get install devscripts` to get the debuild command.

Comment: `debuild` doesn't create a delta source package while `dpkg-buildpackage` does...

Comment: `bzr branch lp:ubuntu/xenial/lightdm

bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "bzr+ssh://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/ubuntu/xenial/lightdm/".`

`bzr branch lp:ubuntu/lightdm

bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "bzr+ssh://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/ubuntu/lightdm/".`

[Ubuntu packaging guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/), specifically [4.2. Getting the source](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/udd-getting-the-source.html#id1) says:

`bzr branch ubuntu:lightdm lightdm.quickswitch

bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "bzr+ssh://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/ubuntu/lightdm/".`

What a mess. :-(