# can I locally patch the fglrx package that comes from the Ubuntu repositories?

Tags: fglrx, packaging, patch

I'm attempting to `apt-get install fglrx` while runnning a custom kernel, and the process is failing when it tries to compile the kernel module.  I found a patch on the net that should take care of my problem.  How do I apply it to a package fetched via apt-get?

I already know how to extract source files from AMD's install program, patch them, and create .deb packages.  That's not what I'm asking here.  I'm not using AMD's installer.

Is there an apt cache somewhere?  Can I edit it?  How do I tell dpkg to unpack a package so I can edit what's inside?  How do I re-package it afterwards?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While you can't patch a proprietary program like fglrx (that's why I don't like them) I assume the patch probably goes into the part that isn't proprietary, namely the part that ties the driver to the kernel. (otherwise you wouldn't have been able to find a patch for it).

Please see [How to download, modify, build and install a Debian source package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81870/how-to-download-modify-build-and-install-a-debian-source-package) for basic instructions.

There are also guides available. See [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1451/63886) for pointers. I have found the IRC chatrooms mentioned particularly helpful.