# Docky: crash when plug/unplug power cable

Tags: 14.04, power-management, docky

Docky keeps on crashing every time I plug in or unplug the AC cable.
I tried solving the problem following the instructions on [this website](http://www.linux-compatible.com/tutorial/docky-closes-after-waking-suspend-ubuntu).

It worked fine for the suspend crash but when I try the power cable one I get this error in the terminal

```
(gedit:27944): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
(gedit:27944): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a known bug in Docky - see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/docky/+bug/1271131).

That said, there is a [fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/docky/+bug/1309706/comments/2) if you're willing to delve into the Docky source code. Otherwise just sit tight until it's fixed on the master branch.

Answer (score 1):

I needed a more step-by-step answer, and found this guide:
http://www.tdrusk.com/wp-content/plugins/really-static/static/2015/01/24/how-to-fix-docky-crashes-when-suspended-or-unplug-in-ubuntu-14-04-and-14-10/

Basically, applies the fix mentioned by Jamie above using the "classic" instructions here [How to download, modify, build and install a Debian source package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81870/how-to-download-modify-build-and-install-a-debian-source-package) to fix, build, and install from source (easier than it sounds, maybe 5 or 6 lines).

For reference, for me the single-line fix was on line 281. 
[image]

And hooray, now I don't have to restart docky all the time!