# Cairo-Dock weather applet not working

Tags: applet, cairo-dock, weather

I have searched high and low for the config file to change the server for the weather applet. Anyone have the file location? A system search yielded no results. The applet stopped working for me and my roomate several days ago.

Comment: switch to another weather service in preferences>weather services

Comment: I could not find any such preferences, Frank. Is it possible that your reply relates to a different weather applet like "my weather indicator" or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and we are not alone: http://www.glx-dock.org/bg_topic.php?t=8945

The update to `libcd-weather.so` as suggested in Garry Garrison's answer (the link to the binary is also mentioned on http://www.glx-dock.org/bg_topic.php?t=8945) did not work for me. Anyway, I tried to fix it myself and I was successful. What I did was the following (on Ubuntu 16.04LTS with cairo-dock 3.4.1):

1. I downloaded the package source using `apt-get source cairo-dock-plug-ins`
2. In the files `cairo-dock-plug-ins-3.4.1/weather/src/applet-config.c` and `cairo-dock-plug-ins-3.4.1/weather/src/applet-read-data.c`, I changed the URLs `http://xml.weather.com` to `http://wxdata.weather.com/wxdata`.
3. Then I followed the instructions presented in [How to download, modify, build and install a Debian source package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81870/how-to-download-modify-build-and-install-a-debian-source-package) in the "Classic" section of the first answer (first rebuild, then install).

After a restart of cairo-dock, the weather plug-in worked normally again. This is basically what is suggested as the necessary patch on http://www.glx-dock.org/bg_topic.php?t=8945, however, with some more details on how to actually perform this patch.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (get the file and replace original):

> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-XSYP5W-8Wea2NWTGJtSkxybEk
>
> I am using Mint 17.3 (64 bit) w/Mate DE and Linux Kernel 3.19.0.22 and
> Cairo-Dock 3.4.0 and the file worked perfectly for me! Thanks for the fix!
> I just copied the file as root in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cairo-dock/libcd-weather.so, and now see my screenshot: https://personal.filesanywhere.com/FS/M.aspx?v=8a6b688d5d65aeba6fa4

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I used your fix as described above... it did not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed weather plug-in on Kubuntu 14.04!!!

-remove all cairo-dock from Synaptic, and install cairo-dock-

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins

Then from https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-XSYP5W-8Wea2NWTGJtSkxybEk

i copied the file as root in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cairo-dock/libcd-weather.so

```
And Cairo-Dock weather applet working!!!
```