# How to build Deja Dup for Ubuntu

Tags: backup, deja-dup, gvfs, debuild

This is both my first question here and my first try to build a custom app for Ubuntu, so I hope I'm not messing it up :)

I want to modify Deja Dup app to make AWS S3 work with IBM COS S3. It should be as simple as change the hardcoded url in the backendS3 file, but I'm not even able to build the vanilla version.

I'm using a just installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 lts
I've downloaded the source following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81870/how-to-download-modify-build-and-install-a-debian-source-package) using the "classic" way. When I run `debuild -us -uc -b` it fails when running the tests. I tried also with make as explained in the HACKING file of the sources with the same result.

As I understand from the test logs, the problem is related to gvfs but after googling it and trying deleting gvfs logs, gvfs medata and executing as root, I don't know what else to do.

I'm attaching the tests and debuild logs. Please tell me what else is needed.

[testlog](https://pastebin.com/BChAcg5K)

[debuild -us -uc -b](https://pastebin.com/d6jmb1jN)

Comment: +1 Good first question. I don't have an answer though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I just build it on Ubuntu 20.04:

1. Clone source code

   ```
    git clone https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/deja-dup.git
   ```

   and `cd ./deja-dup` into the folder.
2. Switch to older branch with gtk3 support for Ubuntu 20.04

   ```
   git checkout --track origin/40`
   ```
3. Update whatever you want to change, eg. [Improve full backup speed with Déjà Dup / Duplicity](https://askubuntu.com/q/1310395/189996)
4. Make and install (including installing missing packages):

   ```
   meson . _build
   ninja -C _build
   ninja -C _build install
   ```

Voilà: [image: custom compiled deja dup]

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a convenient way to check what the newist version is that can handle a given version of Ubuntu/other linux operating system?