# How do I download things from the source repository?

Tags: repository, software-sources, source-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the source code of packages installed through apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get)

I want to look over some programs to help me learn programming, so I enabled the source repository in Ubuntu. How do I download things from that repository?

Comment: ... actually - I think your question is actually a duplicate...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First - create a working folder to download the source in

```
mkdir ~/working_dir
cd ~/working_dir
```

The simplest way is to use the syntax `apt-get source [foo]` where `[foo]` is the package name.

For example - if you wanted to see the source of `nautilus` you would use

```
apt-get source nautilus
```

**basic development tools**

Obviously - if you are intent on playing with code changes you need a few extras.

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts build-essential fakeroot
```

**building packages**

To get install the development packages and dependencies use the syntax

```
sudo apt-get build-dep [foo]
```

Finally - to build the debian package

```
debuild -us -uc
```

Comment: This will download all the files to the current directory. Make sure you run it from where you want the files.