# How to download the source packages for all installed packages?

Tags: apt, gpl

What apt incantations do I need to use to download the source packages for all the installed packages into a directory?  (The use case is GPL compliance when giving an installed Ubuntu system to another person along with a computer.)

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get

Comment: You do not need to bother download all the source code for the person to be GPL compliant. It is enough that the code are publicly available.

Comment: fossilet, [citation-needed] with references to both GPLv3 text and GPLv2 text.

Comment: Not a duplicate of the other question, since the other question is about getting the source of a single package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this..

Create a directory where you want the source for all installed packages to be downloaded, and enter it.

```
mkdir source; cd source
```

Create a file named **getsource.sh**

#### getsource.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
dpkg --get-selections | while read line
do
        package=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
        mkdir $package
        cd $package
        apt-get -q source $package
        cd ..
done
```

Make it executable.

```
chmod a+x getsource.sh
```

Execute it..

```
./getsource.sh
```

And go grab a cup of coffee :)

Comment: Glad to be of assistance (:

Comment: For start thanks for your answer... But I tried to use it on a Debian 9 system and had some problems. Here is the answer that worked for me (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423280/237337).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative for you might be to just hand out the source CDs:

- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/11.10/release/source/

Comment: Thanks. I was browsing from releases.ubuntu.com and failed to locate those images. This option, of course, isn't quite correct if you've run the system update after the initial installation.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu refer to command:

```
apt-get source package-name
```

it is recommended that you only use `apt-get source` as a regular user, because then you can edit files in the source package without needing root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple issues in the accepted answer and with the linked better answer in Unix Stack Exchange. Here's an improved and tested script with comments:

```
#!/bin/bash

# ${Source} doesn't always show the source package name, ${source:Package} does.
# Multiple packages can have the same source, sort -u eliminates duplicates.
dpkg-query -f '${source:Package}\n' -W | sort -u | while read p; do
    mkdir -p $p
    pushd $p

    # -qq very quiet, pushd provides cleaner progress.
    # -d download compressed sources only, do not extract.
    apt-get -qq -d source $p

    popd
done
```

Run as non-root user (`_apt` works). Note any errors as they may indicate packages with no sources available. You may want to run the script with `2>err.log` to parse these manually later.