# failed to download package sources

Tags: downloads, source-packages

I am trying to download package sources for all the installed packages in 14.04.2 release version. I tried the method described here ...  [How to download the source packages for all installed packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119196/how-to-download-the-source-packages-for-all-installed-packages)
It downloaded most of the packages (for the Desktop) but is not able to download about 72 packages, no matter how many times I try. Any help is appreciated. I can post the packages which are failing to download.

Thanks in advance.

Srikanth

Comment: Please add the output of `./getsource.sh` to the question

Comment: We need to see some of the very first error messages in the process. Can you grab the text and post it, or do a screen caption of the errors and post it here at the bottom of your original message?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning up your apt-cache and running any updates:

```
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you still have issues, then change your repo mirror: Open “Update Manager”, then click *Settings* -> *Ubuntu Software* tab, then select *Other...* from the *Download from* and click the *Select Best Server* button. Now try updating/upgrading again.