# How to make ALT+TAB switcher icons smaller

Tags: icons, application-switcher

Is there any way to reduce the size of the default Ubuntu 13.04 window switcher icons, shown when pressing ALT+TAB? Changing Compiz settings (with a text editor, if not in the CCSM GUI) or installing a different window switcher, for example.
Thank you for your help, have a good day.

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know...the size of the default **"Switcher View (Alt+Tab)"** is hardcoded in the Unity source.
 You can try to edit the source code to change the size according to your needs.

---

#### NOTE: I recommend you to do this in a Virtual Machine or in a Test Machine to see if you get the desired results.
In this example I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 with unity 7.0.0 and I will change the "Switcher View" (icons, tiles, etc.) to the half-size.

---

**1)** Make sure you have enable the [Source code repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221899/how-to-download-source-code-with-apt-get).

- Open the Ubuntu Software Center
- In the Menu Bar choose **Edit -> Software Sources**. Click to enable **"Source code repository"**.
  Just in case I use the **"Main Server"** to Download.

[image]

Open a Terminal window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

- `sudo apt-get update`

**2)** In the Terminal type the following to install the necessary packages.

- `sudo apt-get install build-essential python-windowmocker quilt`

**3)** Install build dependencies.

- `sudo apt-get build-dep unity`

**4)** Create a folder to download the source code.

- `mkdir ~/Downloads/src`
- `cd ~/Downloads/src`

**5)** Download the source code & Export variables.

- `apt-get source unity`
- `export QUILT_PATCHES=debian/patches`
- `export EDITOR=gedit`

**6)** Create the patch and Edit the source code.

- `cd unity-7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04/`
- `quilt new 99-custon-switcher-size.patch`
- `quilt edit launcher/SwitcherView.cpp`

---

Edit the lines... **46** to **50**.

[image]

**I changed them from:**

```
  , border_size(50)
  , flat_spacing(20)
  , icon_size(128)
  , minimum_spacing(10)
  , tile_size(150)
```

**To:**

```
  , border_size(25)
  , flat_spacing(10)
  , icon_size(64)
  , minimum_spacing(10)
  , tile_size(75)
```

---

**7)** Build the deb packages.

- `quilt refresh`
- `fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage`

**8)** Install the deb packages.

- `cd ..`
- `sudo dpkg -i *deb`

**9)** Finally you can Restart your machine to see the changes.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's been almost 3 years I've been using Ubuntu. Almost ever since, I wanted to look up how to use the src packages. 3 years I've been procrastinating. Now I have a starting point. **Thank you!**

Comment: Thank you Roman Raguet. Definitely not an operation for a common user. :-)

Comment: @Andrew...Well I wrote and step by step so a user can follow it. you can give it a try.

Comment: @Roman: What happens if I do it and then Ubuntu updates are available and I install them? I think I'll have to install the patch again, is it true? And in this case, do you know how much often that/those packages are updated? Thank you very much.

Comment: @RomanRaguet Please mention fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage will be run with sudo...

Comment: @Shashi if it should be run with `sudo`, why the `fakeroot` then? – So, no, it should not be run with `sudo`.