# What causes the changes in output of ps for GNOME Terminal in 15.04?

Tags: command-line, 15.04, ps

Working on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/650712/72216), I found out that the output of `ps` commands has quite changed in 15.04.

#### A few examples

in 14.04, the output of `ps -e` shows on `gnome-terminal`:

```
$ ps -e
19006 ?        00:00:00 gnome-terminal
```

while in 15.04:

```
$ ps -e
24959 ?        00:00:00 gnome-terminal-
```

(mind the 15 characters)

Curious to the long version, I ran `ps -e ww`:

In 14.04:

```
$ ps -e ww
19006 ?        Sl     0:01 gnome-terminal
```

while in in 15.04

```
$ ps -e ww
24959 ?        Rl     0:01 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server --app-id com.canonical.Terminal.qVQkBaeWjRVoRiJKYQVkNNyrboXUfVrj
```

looking for the application, corresponding to the pid:

In 14.04:

```
$ ps -p 19006 -o comm=
gnome-terminal
```

while in 15.04:

```
$ ps -p 24959 -o comm=
```

again the 15 characters (as expected):

```
gnome-terminal-
```

In the linked question, I solved it by deriving the application name from the `WM_CLASS`, as mentioned in the output of the `xprop` command. I would prefer however to use the "old fashioned" `ps -p 19006 -o comm=`, which is more efficient.

These differences have quite some consequences for usage in scripts. My question is: does anyone have information on what is the reasoning behind this *or* what it is caused by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it has to do with changes made to gnome-terminal. However, scanning the changelogs and news I couldn't find anything specific.

As you can see here in the file list of the 14.04 gnome-terminal package, the /usr/lib/ directory does not even exist.

```
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop
/usr/share/doc/gnome-terminal/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/gnome-terminal/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/gnome-terminal/README
/usr/share/doc/gnome-terminal/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/gnome-terminal/copyright
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/gnome-terminal
/usr/share/man/man1/gnome-terminal.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gnome-terminal.wrapper.1.gz
/usr/share/menu/gnome-terminal
```

In 15.04, the /usr/lib directory *is* included.

```
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-migration
/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
/usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/libterminal-nautilus.so
/usr/share/appdata/gnome-terminal.appdata.xml
/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop
/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.gnome.Terminal.service
/usr/share/doc/gnome-terminal/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/gnome-terminal/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/gnome-terminal/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/gnome-terminal/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/gnome-terminal/copyright
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.Terminal.gschema.xml
/usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/gnome-terminal-search-provider.ini
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/gnome-terminal
/usr/share/man/man1/gnome-terminal.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gnome-terminal.wrapper.1.gz
/usr/share/menu/gnome-terminal
```

`gnome-terminal` is a python script now; the changes were made in version 3.7 so it may have something to do with that.

I have not seen other applications that share this type of change.

Comment: This is helping *a lot*. I was so fixated on what happened to the output of `gnome-terminal` that I forgot to see other applications look as usual. The cause most likely is not what happened to `ps`, but what happened to `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: gnome-terminal is a python script?

Comment: @JacobVlijm yeah, /usr/bin/gnome-terminal is now a python script and it calls gnome-terminal-server as a subprocess on line 49

Comment: That must be it, nice research!! Thanks a lot!