# how to find the lastest source code for "unzip"?

Tags: source-code

I have version 6.0-4ubuntu1 installed, but here ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/src/ i see only version 6.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the *current* version (that you have installed) first check what package we're really talking about:

```
$ dpkg -S `which unzip`
unzip: /usr/bin/unzip
```

Not all binaries belong to a package of the same name. This one does.
When you know the package, you can download the source that went into it, like so:

```
apt-get source unzip
```

Of course that requires you to have [the source repositories enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221899/how-to-download-source-code-with-apt-get) but that's simple enough to fix if you don't.

To compile it you'll need `unzip`'s dependencies. Again, `apt-get` can help:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep unzip
```

And then you can follow the standard instructions for the application you're compiling (usually some form of `./configure` and `make`) but you may wish to package it before installing. `checkinstall` comes in pretty handy here as a quick package builder. See this for more:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo

Comment: thank you. A few more questions. Where is the downloaded source go, and is it safe to just edit and recompile it?

Comment: It should get downloaded to the current working path. If you want to recompile it you'll need to `sudo apt-get build-dep unzip` before you can compile it. Warning: for some packages the build-dep is ***epic***.