# Change size of Panel icons

Tags: unity, indicator, customization, notification-area

How to change the size of the icons in the notification area of the Panel (I've added a screenshot).

I've tried to change the size of the top bar too but failed. If you can help me with that as well please do tell.

[image]

Comment: You could have a look at the setting for "[Scale of menus and titlebars](https://askubuntu.com/a/462023/383125)" - note that this will make many things bigger / smaller, not just the icons.

Comment: @JonasCz yup, mentioned that already. That scales up overall User Interface though, including the bottom launcher

Comment: Actually . . . this gives me an idea . . .

Comment: Nah, I tried command line ways, i tried  compizconfig  - nothing there.  The only way to get around this is to use the "Scale of menus and titlebars" but then decrease the size of icons on launcher via Settings->Appearance menu.  So that's something we have to live with - menu and title bar as well as launcher have to be scaled separately

Comment: This question has infor about menu bar size of Unity, not Icon though http://askubuntu.com/questions/342734/increase-menu-bar-size?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

short answer : those cannot change size. You can change their style with themes, but then size is fixed.

What can be done, however, is to use Settings->Display options to scale top panel up , but that will scale up over all UI, so this might not be exactly what you want

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate....I am sorry for asking such a silly thing.....Very Embarrassing... :P

Comment: @HashikDonthineni nothing embarrassing here :)  Unity overall is very configurable, but unfortunately top panel is just something fixed. Been glad to help :)