# How to change Nautilus to show "file system" instead of "computer"?

Tags: 13.04, nautilus, filesystem, filemanager

**Nautilus** use to have the label for the file system in it's tree as "**File System**". Recently that was changed to now show "**Computer**" in the tree to open the file system. Regardless of why this change was made, how do I change it back?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know... to change this label you should edit the nautilus Source Code.

**NOTE:** *In this example I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 with nautilus (Files) 3.6.3*

**1)** Make sure you have enable the [Source code repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221899/how-to-download-source-code-with-apt-get)

- Open the Ubuntu Software Center and in the Menu Bar choose **Edit -> Software Sources**. 
  Click to enable "Source code repository".

Just in case I use the **"Main Server"** to Download.

[image]

**2)** Open a Terminal and install the necessary packages.

- `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

**3)** Install build dependencies

- `sudo apt-get build-dep nautilus`

**4)** Create a folder to download the source code.

- `mkdir ~/Downloads/src`
- `cd ~/Downloads/src`

**5)** Download the source code.

- `apt-get source nautilus`

**6)** Edit the file "nautilus-places-sidebar.c"

Search for the line **3261** to edit.

[image]

Replace "Computer" for "File System".

To edit:

- `gedit nautilus-3.6.3/src/nautilus-places-sidebar.c`

**BEFORE:**

> sidebar->hostname = g_strdup (_("Computer"));

**AFTER:**

> sidebar->hostname = g_strdup (_("File System"));

In one command would be:

- `sed -i '3261s/Computer/File\ System/' ~/Downloads/src/nautilus-3.6.3/src/nautilus-places-sidebar.c`

**7)** Go to the "nautilus-3.6.3" folder to build the deb packages.

- `cd nautilus-3.6.3/`
- `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b`

**8)** Now you can install the deb packages.

- `cd ..`
- `sudo dpkg -i *deb`

**9)** Finally you can logout and Login to see the changes.

**BEFORE:**

[image]

**AFTER:**

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: debian builds of nautilus use a source format of `3.0 (quilt)` so after making any changes to the source they should be committed before using dpkg-buildpackage. As in `dpkg-source --commit`, ect.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to get the raring nautilus source, edit `/src/nautilus-places-sidebar.c` & rebuild. Preferable to rebuild as debian packages.

The edit would be something like this,  -

```
--- nautilus-3.6.3.orig/src/nautilus-places-sidebar.c
+++ nautilus-3.6.3/src/nautilus-places-sidebar.c
@@ -3258,7 +3258,7 @@ nautilus_places_sidebar_init (NautilusPl
              G_CALLBACK(desktop_setting_changed_callback),
              sidebar);

-   sidebar->hostname = g_strdup (_("Computer"));
+   sidebar->hostname = g_strdup (_("File System"));
g_dbus_proxy_new_for_bus (G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM,
              G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_GET_INVALIDATED_PROPERTIES,
              NULL,
```