# How to I change the root foldername that shown in Nautilus

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, hostname

It used to be just "Computer", but recently I have changed/edited my hostname. After that, the root folder is showing up as the hostname and not as "Computer".

[image: Screenshot]

In the place of "zeus-Dell-System-Vostro-3450", it used to be just "Computer". How can I revert it back?

Comment: If you right click it, is there a Rename... option?

Comment: Ya but its greyed out.Should I open in giving sudo privilege?

Comment: I have tried sudo nautilus / but the option is still grey.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can rename it then, short of rebuilding Nautilus. Hopefully someone has a solution.

Comment: Have you tried this http://askubuntu.com/questions/344891/how-to-change-nautilus-to-show-file-system-instead-of-computer ? Worked on 14.04 too

Comment: Sorry for the question .... but that is not simply the label of the disk?!

Answer (score 1):

Go to system settings, under system click Details, then click Overview on the left and were it says Device name you can edit what is shown for the root drive under Nautilus. This will change the hostname to Computer also after reboot so just change your hostname to what you want it to be using 
gksudo gedit /etc/hostname and gksudo gedit /etc/hosts. After reboot Nautilus will show the drive as Computer and your hostname will be whatever you have set it to be, you can check this by just typing hostname in terminal.