# Need help to change name of highlighted below

Tags: command-line

[image]

I want to change this name to "Computer" which was earlier. It was changed by me accidentally but later on I forgot the method to change it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/820833/how-to-i-change-the-root-foldername-that-shown-in-nautilus/825314#825314

Comment: @SpasSpasov, is it actually a _duplicate_ as he desires to _change the name_ of the connected devices _not a default nautilus folder name_, the method of changing the names are they the same?

Comment: Hi, @George. We actually don't know what Uddeshya really has done. That is just my guess. I think change of the partition name will not solve the problem, because I've tried it. To change the default nautilus folder name he must be followed some manual like this: http://askubuntu.com/a/344908/566421 ... and recompile the Nautilus. But it is more complicated and if he was done these steps, I think, he will remembered what he has done.

Comment: thank u friends but i have corrected it. What I actually did was went to "Details" (from ubuntu search center) and changed the device name to "Computer".

Answer (score 0):

You should find out what's the drive name, and you can do that runnig `fdisk -l`.

Assuming that the highlighted item is names **/dev/sda1**, to change the labels use one of these commands:

```
sudo e2label /dev/sda1 Computer
```

or

```
sudo sudo tune2fs -L Computer /dev/sda1
```

Comment: thank u friends but i have corrected it. What I actually did was went to "Details" (from ubuntu search center) and changed the device name to "Computer"