# Change the name of the Ubuntu label ('Computer') in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, partitioning

I renamed the two partitions of windows and Ubuntu (dual boot) via GNOME Disks, restarted, but when I open Nautilus in the 'Other Locations' section I see only the label of windows changed, while the Ubuntu label remains under the name of' Computer is there a way to change this label?

[I mean this label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrF5Q.png)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Gnome disks, but I know if you use Gparted, click on the disk and choose "Label," it will let you permanently change the disk label across the whole system. You may want to try that first. Also, you can use this in the terminal:

```
sudo e2label /dev/sdOfCurrentDisk "mydiskname"
```

where sd is the partition or disk you want to change and the part in quotes is the new name you want. I think the reason your change didnt work is because it only changed the name it was mounted with and not the actual label. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately none of the two methods work, the name I changed via GNOME Disks I noticed that it was just the Label that you see in GParted, even using e2label I change the name of that Label but on nautilus it still remains' Computer 'as a Label.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood your request. Are you trying to change the part where it says "computer" in the file structure - like Home, Desktop, Computer - or am i still misunderstanding. Originally I thought you wanted to change the disk name. If you just want to change the "computer" part, open a terminal, then sudo nautilus, then right click computer (or whatever its called now) and go to rename. Also, this question seems to have an answer as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/820833/how-to-i-change-the-root-foldername-that-shown-in-nautilus

Comment: I modified the question by adding to the image of what I mean, I am not able to rename simply by right-clicking, and the answer you linked does not solve my problem, that seems like an older version of nautilus, as you can see from the image that I added, going to rename the label of the windows partition the name is displayed correctly, while renaming the ubuntu partition also the label remains 'Computer'.

Comment: Had a comment and deleted it. Basically, this is more of an issue about how to rename that icon rather than label a disk. Let me dig around and see if anybody else has attempted this.

Comment: I finally found something. The only solution seems to be to download the Nautilus source code, change the computer label in that and then rebuild and install the application. Here is a link with instructions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/344891/how-to-change-nautilus-to-show-file-system-instead-of-computer?rq=1

Comment: Thank you, I've understand! But so what happen to the previous Nautilus package? I mean, after that I've done the procedure linked by you, the original Nautilus package is replaced?

Comment: I should have mentioned that in my previous comment. You will need to remove Nautilus with 'sudo apt-get remove nautilus' and then install the re-compiled app with the source code you modified. Make sure you only remove the package and dont purge it so that you dont remove the additional libraries that come packaged with it.