# How to increase icons and fonts in Nautilus sidebar (left pane)?

Tags: nautilus

I imagine there is a setting for that but I cannot find it...

Comment: Yes, I also want to know is there any way to increase the icon size of side pane in `nautilus` just like we do in `thunar` :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't do it with configurations but you can recompile nautilus with your own icon size (and it's not too complicated). I've compiled it 5 minutes ago and this was the first time I compiled a thing from ubuntu, but it worked, so you can do it, too.

[Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=549360) is a nice How-To, i did it this way with nautilus 3.4.2 (only difference: the line to change is line 369, i searched for "pixbuf = nautilus_icon", the value to change the icon size is icon_size)

For example I changed it to 5, so the icons are very small

original:

[image]

with new size:

[image]