# How to remove right click format option to a disk icon in the launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, customization

How to remove right click **"format"** option from a disk icon in the launcher as it can 
lead to formatting by mistake.

Comment: You'll not be able to format a disk drive until you want to do it intentionally.. Always it'll prompt for your password..

Comment: Thanks Kumar but still I want to know if that option can be removed.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know...the **Format** option is **hardcoded** in the *Unity source*.
 You can try to edit source code to remove the format item.

---

#### NOTE: I recommend you to do this in a Virtual Machine or in a Test Machine to see is everything is OK. *(In this example I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity 5.20.0)*.

---

**1)** Make sure you have enable the [Source code repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221899/how-to-download-source-code-with-apt-get)

- Open the Ubuntu Software Center.
- In the Menu Bar choose **Edit -> Software Sources**. Click to enable **"Source code repository"**.
  Just in case I use the **"Main Server"** to Download.

[image]

Open a Terminal window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

- `sudo apt-get update`

**2)** In the Terminal type the following to install the necessary packages.

- `sudo apt-get install build-essential quilt`

**3)** Install build dependencies.

- `sudo apt-get build-dep unity`

**4)** Create a folder to download the source code.

- `mkdir ~/Downloads/src`
- `cd ~/Downloads/src`

**5)** Download the source code & Export variables.

- `apt-get source unity`
- `export QUILT_PATCHES=debian/patches`
- `export EDITOR=gedit`

**6)** Create the patch and Edit the source code.

- `cd unity-5.20.0/`
- `quilt new 99_no_format_option.patch`
- `quilt edit plugins/unityshell/src/DeviceLauncherIcon.cpp`

**Remove the lines... from 171 to 185.**

[image]

Save the changes.

**7)** Build the deb packages.

- `quilt refresh`
- `fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage`

**8)** Install the deb packages.

- `cd ..`
- `sudo dpkg -i *deb`

**9)** Finally you can logout and Login to see the changes.

#### Before:

[image]

#### After:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: You went and dirtied your hands with the source code D:!