# What blobs are in the Ubuntu kernel, release 15.10?

Tags: system-installation, kernel, proprietary, free-software

It was indicated that my question was a lot like the question following this, the edit suggested explaining why it is different. This is about the kernel, not about repositories. Refer to the following question and see the difference: [Which repository are free software on 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270221/which-repository-are-free-software-on-12-04)

Additonally, I am not asking HOW to install a blob free kernel. I am asking for a solid answer about which are in it. The vanilla kernel includes blobs. If you are telling me there are none, please point to your sources so I can check them out. I am NOT criticizing Ubuntu, just looking for interesting information. Opinions are not interesting. Facts would help me.

I see in one reply that there are NO BLOBs in the kernel Ubuntu included. However, the vanilla kernel does have blobs. Is the Ubuntu kernel a different build? In 2013 it did: [Does Ubuntu contain Non-free kernel blobs and other non-free system components?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387551/does-ubuntu-contain-non-free-kernel-blobs-and-other-non-free-system-components)

I have read in the answer to the above question that the option of not including proprietary software is available when Ubuntu is installed. I have seen the option for not installing some mpeg decoding stuff, but have seen nothing about installing a blob-free kernel.

SO, assuming the kernel has blobs in it, regardless of the options we choose (and I'm neutral about the question of whether that's a good thing or not) I would really like to know what blobs are in there.

IF I am mistaken, THEN my question is this: Does Ubuntu have a separate builds, with no blobs in one and one with blobs? ELSE are the blobs contained in loadable modules?

Comment: See https://trisquel.info/ and http://www.fsfla.org/ikiwiki/selibre/linux-libre/

Comment: Just don't install anything from the `restricted` or `multiverse` repositories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which repository are free software on 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270221/which-repository-are-free-software-on-12-04)

Comment: There are NO blobs in Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: Where do you think the kernel comes from, if not the repositories?

Comment: I edited this question. It is not about free repositories, it is specifically about blobs in the kernel. I would like to see Pilot6's source saying there are NO blobs in the Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: Ubuntu kernels do not contain any blobs. You can see kernel sources, e.g. at http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-xenial.git  You probably do not know what kernel is.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I do know and I cannot possibly follow the kernel sources, and am unfamiliar with the use of GIT as I am not a very advanced progammer.  I can, however read insults pretty clearly and wonder why you must insult me. So very sorry to have irked you.

Comment: Where did you find insults?

Comment: I think Pilot6 wanted to say "I think you have a misconception of what a kernel is" which is how I would have stated the same impression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu kernels do not contain any blobs.

When you install Ubuntu the default is not to install any proprietary packages.

So the answer is: If you do not enable proprietary packages or do not install any proprietary drivers afterwards, you get a blob free installation.

There is an exception, but it is not in kernel. The `linux-firmware` package. It contains hardware firmware, that is set of blobs and it is installed by default. But this code is not supposed to be executed by CPU and can't be considered as "blobs" in the common meaning.

Comment: Depends on how reviews the Ubuntu kernel, which is why I think the question is off topic as opinion based. Linux-libre certainly feels teh Ubuntu kernel contains binary blobs -) See http://www.fsfla.org/ikiwiki/selibre/linux-libre/

Comment: Show me a in-tree kernel blob. I gave a link to Ubuntu kernels sources. So where is the blob?

Comment: I have no intention of reviewing the ubuntu kernel for "binary blobs", if you are interested, contact triaquil and linux-libre - they will point them out to you gladly- https://launchpad.net/~linux-libre/+archive/ubuntu/ppa jxself is very nice and usually on IRC. MOst of the time there is disagreement, but if you want, run a diff on the libre source in the ppa.

Comment: changelogs here - http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~linux-libre/linux-libre/packaging/changes

Comment: I do not need to do it. I do not consider firmware as blobs. The same way you can look for bios free computers. It is more blob than a firmware.

Comment: thank you all for the info. I did not know firmware are not blobs. But I didn't mean the bios, just firmware for stuff like some wifi hardware I've heard doesn't have open firmware. This has been educational and helpful-also I got a great response from:http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273238/intermediate-programmer-seeks-comprehensible-info-on-which-blobs-are-included-in?noredirect=1#comment474367_273238

Comment: Oh, I noticed a mention that the question is off topic. I wasn't seeking opinions, just information so I could check out what hardware there was firmware blobs for (assuming there were some in there) and also to check out any other proprietary binary code-referred to as blobs. Just the facts is all wanted.

Comment: @Pilot6 - Again, that is why I feel the question is off topic, opinions vary depending on who you ask

Comment: oops. meant to answer my own question but started this comment I can't erase

Comment: On https://www.gnu.org/distros/common-distros.html, FSF says: "the version of Linux, the kernel, included in Ubuntu contains firmware blobs". It is also mentioned in the link https://askubuntu.com/questions/387551/does-ubuntu-contain-non-free-kernel-blobs-and-other-non-free-system-components shared in the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Info from reddit][1]As for what I meant by "blob," this link explains it clearly. I need no opinions - Wikipedia explained it clearly enough for me.
I read that Debian "deblobs" their kernel and that Ubuntu is built around the Debian distro. So I looked further and found this: [1]: https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/3ndgx0/how_to_deblob_vanilla_kernel/
So, now at least I have a working understanding of what a 'blob' is, I know where to find more information, and I've learned to do the research myself because otherwise I'll drown under a sea of opinions. I wonder if ANY QUESTION can be on topic in this forum, since everything is subject to off-the-cuff opinions. If you don't like the heat get out of the kitchen, as they say, so thank you, and adios. I'd hoped for more but learned I must stand on my own. Good luck everyone!

Comment: Note that Debian and Ubuntu have a different kernel version. Also on https://www.gnu.org/distros/common-distros.html, FSF says: "the version of Linux, the kernel, included in Ubuntu contains firmware blobs".