# Unable to build GTK+ 3

Tags: gnome, gtk, gtk3, gnome-calculator

I am getting started with open source contributions and need to make-build the gnome-calculator.
I recently downloaded gnome 3 (ubuntu) and need to build the gnome-calculator which needs gtk+3. 
I downloaded  gtk+-3.12.0.tar.xz  from this site: http://www.gtk.org/download/linux.php

After running  `./configure --prefix=/opt/gtk` , I get the following problem:
http://fpaste.org/101402/

However, package atk could not be located.

**EDIT**
Installing it from the repositories gives an older version that is not compatible with gnome-calculator ... I need to install the specific version only.

Comment: Why don't you just install it from the repositories?

Comment: installing what is not compatible with gnome-calculator?  Perhaps you should explain why you need to install gnome-calculator 3.12. Gnome-calculator 3.10 in 14.04 is adequate for most people - what specifically do you need in 3.12?  I presume you are actually on ubuntu 14.04 at the moment?

Comment: I intend to fix this:https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=694863

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just install the current version and its sources? Should be as easy as

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-calculator
```

and then (having the sources repository activated)

```
apt-get source gnome-calculator
```

And then try to compile it (to start from a known point) and start hacking.

Reference here: [How do I get and modify the source code of packages installed through apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get)