# How to compile GRUB2

Tags: grub2

I'm looking for the way to build GRUB2 from scratch. I'm not using `grub-mkimage` or anything like that. I downloaded the source code with `apt-get source grub2` and unzipped the Debian tarball. Inside the folder there is configure tool or autogen file. `make` asks me to specify a build target. Can anyone tell me how to begin with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile to a .deb, have a look at this question: [How do I get and modify the source code of packages installed through apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get)

Otherwise, `./configure && make && make install` is often the way to go, in the root folder of the source package.

Comment: No, I don't want to compile a Debian software package. I want to use something like `make install`. There is no `./configure`.