# Replace prebuilt package with self-compiled version

Tags: upgrade, updates, compiling, install-from-source

I need to update my Point Cloud Library (PCL) that I installed via [official instructions](http://pointclouds.org/downloads/linux.html) with my own version that I just compiled according to [this manual](http://pointclouds.org/downloads/source.html). The reason is I need to fix a bug in PCL which is present in the pre-built package that I installed originally.

I do "sudo make install" as in the last step but when I compile my application the bug is still present. If I list libpcl version like this

```
dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | grep libpcl
```

it outputs 1.7+trusty1 for libpcl-all package and 1.7.1-3+trusty2 for other libpcl- packages. My compiled version shold be 1.7.2.

Comment: Err... skype? Wrong copy & paste?

Comment: I'd first remove the precompiled stuff using `apt-get purge libpcl-all` and then compile and install my own built.

Comment: This does not help - shows 1.7.1-3+trusty2 still and my fix is not being applied.

Comment: That was just a hint, of course you need to purge all the packages you'd like to replace my self-built ones.

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu, this manual represents a wrong way to install from source something, that exists in the library. The right one is this:

1. `apt-get source <package>`
2. `sudo apt-get build-dep <package>`
3. `cd <package>`
4. `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b`
5. `dpkg -i <package>.deb`

Full instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get)
For kernel and libs procedure is different.

Comment: Sadly "apt-get source libpcl-all" does not work as it probably is being installed via PPA repository? It outputs following: Picking 'pcl-defaults' as source package instead of 'libpcl-all'
E: Unable to find a source package for pcl-defaults

Comment: Then you will need to learn about `checkinstall` utility which is the safets way to install from arbitrary source code. Just set your package version to 9999 to make it precedent all others.