# PCL Ubuntu Installation

Tags: software-installation, ppa, libraries

I have been trying to install PCL for linux on Ubuntu 14.10: http://pointclouds.org/downloads/linux.html

So far, I have done the first two steps,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl
sudo apt-get update
```

But it fails on the third:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpcl-all
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libpcl-all
```

What can I do to solve this problem? I have looked online, but all the existing threads do not seem to have a working resolution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install `libpcl1`, it's in the Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcl1
```

---

Or as @Fabby said, compile your own version:

```
sudo apt-get install git
cd
git clone git@github.com:PointCloudLibrary/pcl.git
cd pcl
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

Note the missing development libraries, eg:

```
-- checking for module 'eigen3'
--   package 'eigen3' not found
-- checking for module 'flann>=1.7.0'
--   package 'flann>=1.7.0' not found
```

and install the development libraries with, eg:

```
sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev
sudo apt-get install libflann-dev
```

Start the compiler with `make`

```
make
```

And install

- the classic way `make install`

  ```
  sudo make install
  ```
- with `checkinstall`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install checkinstall
  sudo checkinstall
  ```

Comment: `libpcl1` is Portable Coroutine Library, not Point Cloud Library.

Answer (score 0):

Because for [your version of Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/~v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/+archive/ubuntu/pcl?field.series_filter=utopic) this library does not exist in this PPA.

To solve this, [you need to build from source instead](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543560/replace-prebuilt-package-with-self-compiled-version).

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: He, this is a link only answer =P =)