# default package: tar .xz or tar .bz2?

Tags: 12.04, browser, tar, opera

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit, 2 GB of memory.
Which default package should I select when asked before downloading an application like the Opera Web Browser?

Comment: Check my edits at the bottom of my answer for installing `opera`.

Answer (score 2):

Normally in Ubuntu the packages that you can install directly via command line (`sudo apt-get install <package>`) or software center has the `.deb` format. Here all the dependencies will be automatically fixed, so you don't need to worry about anything just use the command line or software center to install a package, the package manager will take the  right decision for you.

If you want you can also download the source files (`sudo apt-get source <package>`) of the packages available at the repositories, normally have the format of compressed archive i.e. `tar.gz` or `tar.bz2` format. Normally you don't need to download the source files of the packages that are already available at the `.deb` format. If you need to really build from source you can check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/28373/216503).

Now what about a package that is not available at repository? Well, in that case you need to look for a `.deb` availability of the package. If `.deb` is found you can [install it via `dpkg`](https://askubuntu.com/a/40781/216503)(`sudo dpkg -i package.deb`), but remember you need to satisfy the dependencies yourself.

What if the `.deb` format is not available then you can download the source file of the package in `.tar.gz` ot `tar.bz2` or any other format and then uncompresses and compile the package yourself. Normally there would be a `README` file inside telling what you need to do to install the package.

### Opera 32 bit :

In case of Opera 32 bit, go to [this page](http://www.opera.com/download/guide/?os=linux-i386) and just hit "Free Download For Linux i386", don't bother about the package format as it will be downloaded as a `.deb` package (you typically don't need need `tar.gz` or `tar.bz2` when `.deb` is available). Then install it via command line taking help [from here](https://askubuntu.com/a/40781/216503).

Xen2050 made a good point that you can also use official repository or a PPA to download Opera. If you do so you the can just use `apt-get` as usual to install Opera directly. For example you can do the following to add the official Opera repository and install opera:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list'
sudo bash -c 'wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | apt-key add -'
```

Now as the repository and GPG key has been added you can just issue the following to install Opera:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install opera
```

Comment: Or add repositories (like getdeb, or just "sections" like restricted, universe, multiverse) or PPA's

Comment: @Xen2050: Good point..adding..

Comment: Hello heemayl and @Xen2050, it seems that this version of Opera is obsolete and not available. I downloaded the file in my Download folder, but the terminal said it cannot access to the archive and there is no file of this type. Thanks. I will continue using Firefox and Chromium. I am new in the Linux world and I am happy having learned a few things.