# How can I get the source code of a command?

Tags: command-line, source-code

In this particular case the **reset** command. I want to *read* the code of this command.

TY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For commands that are actually present on the system, the query mode of `dpkg` is often helpful: either `dpkg -S` or (equivalently) `dpkg-query -S` e.g.

```
$ dpkg-query -S $(which reset)
ncurses-bin: /usr/bin/reset
```

For querying the contents of packages that are not already installed, there is the `apt-file` utility (not installed by default, but available from the Universe repository)

```
$ apt-file search -x '/reset$'
crossfire-common: /usr/share/games/crossfire/wizhelp/reset
hybserv: /usr/share/hybserv/help/chanserv/level/reset
ncurses-bin: /usr/bin/reset
ns2-examples: /usr/share/doc/ns2/examples/tcl/test/test-output-tcpReset/reset
```

Alternatively, you can search at http://packages.ubuntu.com/ either by package name or contents.

---

To actually obtain the package's source code once you have identified it, see [How do I get and modify the source code of packages installed through apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-and-modify-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get)

Comment: Suggestions: 1) `apt-file` not installed by default, so you might want to mention that in the answer. 2) OP wants to read source code of the command, so you may want to include `apt-get source` command into your answer. I suggest simplifying with `apt-get source $(dpkg-query -S $(which reset) | awk -F ':' '{print $1}')`

Comment: Thanks @serg - I thought *"available from the Universe repository"* might be a strong enough hint that's it's not installed by default ;)

Comment: Yes, that implies it.

Comment: And you can use the awesome debsources ... https://sources.debian.net/src/ncurses/ and browse the code (`reset` is a complex one, I think is a script generated on the fly with some Makefile magic, see https://sources.debian.net/src/ncurses/6.0%2B20150810-1/progs/Makefile.in/#L173 )