# Where can I find the source code for ubuntu software center

Tags: python, software-center, dbus, policykit

I'm stuck on an issue with polkit authentication in python. I know USC is written in python and they've implemented that. I'd like to know how they do that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy the source of the package `software-center` to the local computer:

```
apt source software-center
```

To make sure that you have everything that is needed to build the package from source:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep software-center
```

See [How do I get and modify the source code of packages installed through apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-and-modify-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get).

An very useful resource is the official [Ubuntu package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) page; it allows you to find the dependencies, list of installed files and source tarballs for any package installed by any (recent-ish) version of Ubuntu.

(Edited to correspond with Tatakai Wasumi's observation.)

Comment: I ended up running `sudo apt source software-center` instead it works. Thank you.

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi: I edited the answer to correspond to your observation.