# How to change jump time in totem media player?

Tags: 16.04, totem

How to change jump time in totem media player? It's by default 60 sec jump forward and 15 sec jump back.

Answer (score 5):

- <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>: forward 15 seconds
- <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>left arrow</kbd>: back for 5 seconds

Comment: Can I manually set a time?

Comment: Nope. There is no option to set this.

Comment: This cannot configure it in version 3.34

Comment: This issue is still present years later. Having different times for going back and forward is very inconvenient when looking for something; I wish I could set them both to 5 seconds..

Answer (score 4):

You can still download the source code and modify a couple lines.

This is rather easy.

- Ensure your configuration allows you to download source code directly from `apt` (open "Software and Updates", check the "Source code" box, if unchecked, close and click "Reload")
- `cd` somewhere where you can get the source code and work on it

Some commands

```
apt source totem          # get the source code
sudo build-dep totem      # get the necessary dependencies to build totem

cd totem-x.y.z            # where x.y.z is the version you just downloaded

dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b    # builds the package (.deb)
```

The program `totem` itself should be there to be executed (from where you are)

```
obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/totem    # (on a 64 bits system)
```

Once you get here, it's easy to modify the forward / backward times, then repeat the build procedure (dpkg-buildpackage)

Open the C source code from your favorite editor (vi, emacs, ed...)

```
vi src/totem-object.c
```

You should see near line 70 (your version might differ)

```
#define SEEK_FORWARD_SHORT_OFFSET   15
#define SEEK_BACKWARD_SHORT_OFFSET  -5

#define SEEK_FORWARD_LONG_OFFSET   10*60
#define SEEK_BACKWARD_LONG_OFFSET  -3*60
```

adjust the numbers (seconds) to what you want then repeat the build procedure.

You can execute *this* version you just compiled (as shown above), or uninstall totem (`apt remove totem`) and then install the new `.deb`.

<sub>*Credit*: got help from this great post https://askubuntu.com/a/28373/6619</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Based on [e2-e4](https://askubuntu.com/users/6619/e2-e4)'s Solution, here is a way how you
can also add the modified player to the menu entry
and set it as your default media player:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

**Step 1)** Get source code:

```sh
~$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin/totem
~$ cd /usr/local/bin/totem
…/$ sudo apt source totem    # get source code
…/$ sudo apt build-dep totem # get dependencies
…/$ cd totem-XYZ             # where XYZ is the downloaded version
…/totem-XYZ$ xdg-open src/totem-object.c  # modify seek offsets in source file
```

**Step 2)** Modify jump time seconds:

```c
#define SEEK_FORWARD_SHORT_OFFSET    5 // [shift]+[right]
#define SEEK_BACKWARD_SHORT_OFFSET  -5 // [shift]+[left]

#define SEEK_FORWARD_LONG_OFFSET    10 // [ctrl]+[right]
#define SEEK_BACKWARD_LONG_OFFSET  -10 // [ctrl]+[left]
```

**Step 3)** Build debian package:

```sh
…/totem-XYZ$ sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b
```

**Step 4)** Run custom totem video player:

```sh
…/totem-XYZ$ ./obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/totem
```

**Step 5)** Set modified totem media player as default ([Reference](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/desktop_entries#File_example)):

```sh
…/totem-XYZ$ cd ~/
~$ wget -c https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/GNOME_Video_icon_2019.svg?download -O totem-logo.svg # get icon
~$ sudo mv totem-logo.svg /usr/share/pixmaps/ # move icon
~$ cat << EOT >> totem_media_player.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Modified Totem Player
Comment=A free media player for the GNOME desktop environment.
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/totem-logo.svg
Exec="/usr/local/bin/totem/totem-3.34.1/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/totem" %f
Terminal=false
Categories=AudioVideo
EOT
~$ desktop-file-validate totem_media_player.desktop           # validate file
~$ mv totem_media_player.desktop ~/.local/share/applications  # move file
~$ update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications        # update menu entries
```

**Step 6)** Right click on a `.mp4` video file and change default application:

[image]

**Step 7)** Done.