# Missing dependency: text

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

On Ubuntu 16.04 I am following the instructions from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-and-modify-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get) post to modify `twidge` program from the ubuntu sources. When invoking the instruction to create a deb file (`dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b`), I get this error message.

```
setup: At least the following dependencies are missing:
text >=0.11.2.0 && <0.12
```

I have been unable to solve this problem using search engines, and wonder if anybody might know what I have to do.

Comment: Which package are you trying to build? On which Ubuntu version?

Comment: twidge on ubuntu 1604

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be dependency/compilation bug of [twidge](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/twidge).
I can't compile even after installation of all Haskell -dev packages.
So even with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get build-dep twidge
sudo apt-get install libghc-*-dev # not really necessary, just for sure
```

I can't compile it with

```
apt-get source twidge --compile
```

So I reported [bug 1746069 to launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/twidge/+bug/1746069).

If you selected this package for learning purposes you can start with different and simpler one.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I have already done this, which is why I'm extra confused about why there is a dependency problem.

Comment: I get the same error while compiling original package `apt-get source twidge --compile`. I'll update my answer on any success.

Comment: It does not compile. I reported [bug 1746069 to launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/twidge/+bug/1746069).