# Editing Programs

Tags: installed-programs

I've been checking out source codes of some Linux software. For instance, if I were to run `cd /usr/bin` and type `sudo nano libreoffice`, I would see the LibreOffice source code.

However most programs are different. For instance  `sudo nano cmatrix` shows a lot of junk with few recognizable strings of text. It does state at the bottom of nano "Converted from Mac format". I'm not sure what that means, and I don't see it every time I see junk like this.

How can I see the source code of a program like this, or can't I?

Note I'm looking in `/usr/bin` based on [this diagram](http://blog.danyll.com/content/images/2015/04/linux_directory_map_hd.png). Also, note that this isn't restricted to nano. I've also tried vi, but I prefer nano.

Comment: also /usr/bin/libreoffice is not the source code for libre office.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get and modify the source code of packages installed through apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-and-modify-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get)

Comment: It is most likely compiled...However, you can find the source code for LibreOffice... there --> https://github.com/LibreOffice

Comment: If you do `file cmatrix` you'll probably see that this file is a binary (ELF).

Comment: @dsstorefile perhaps this only works for programs installed by `apt-get`? I only get `E: Unable to find a source package for ___` .
I've installed all of my programs with `apt`

Answer (score 3):

That is not the "source code" for `libreoffice`, it's just a shell script that sets up the environment and starts the real `libreoffice`.

If you install the `apt-src` package, you can use it to download the actual source of ubuntu packages. Read `man apt-src`.

Comment: Or use `apt-get source` directly.