# How to build gcc-mips-linux-gnu from source

Tags: 18.04, apt, gcc, cross-compilation

I've been using the [gcc-mips-linux-gnu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gcc-mips-linux-gnu) package, and now I want to make a small modification to the compiler. How can I build the exact same package locally?

I already tried using `apt-get source` based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/28373/1219186), but that does not retrieve the gcc source. The "source" retrieved is just a few shell scripts. Running

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -us -b
```

takes less than two minutes (red flag since building gcc should take longer), and the resulting debs don't contain the compiler binary.

I've also tried to obtain the gcc source directly, and build using the configure command that mips-linux-gnu-gcc says it was built with, but that yields many different compilation issues.

```
% mips-linux-gnu-gcc -v                                                   
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=mips-linux-gnu-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/mips-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
Target: mips-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libsanitizer --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-multilib --with-arch-32=mips32r2 --with-fp-32=xx --with-lxc1-sxc1=no --enable-targets=all --with-arch-64=mips64r2 --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=mips-linux-gnu --program-prefix=mips-linux-gnu- --includedir=/usr/mips-linux-gnu/include
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
```