# How is PPA built?

Tags: ppa, source-code

I have a question about the PPA structure.
I don't mean one package, but the PPA system, etc.

As I understand it, the PPA backend is launchpad and its code is available under launchpad.

And what about the client? Where can I find the source code of packages for PPA support or a modified apt for this purpose?

Comment: Is this what are you looking for: https://askubuntu.com/q/28372/26246

Comment: You use a PPA as per any other source on a Ubuntu system, there is no difference to *clients* as you put it.

Comment: Please mention a program package, that you would like to use. -- I'm responsible for the package [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), but should be able to explain and try to help you use also other ppa packages.